# Custom Middleware in Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-middleware

I have created a Reducer with `createSlice` and want to reset|modify the state of this slice every time a `dispatch` matches one of the cases of the reducer.

Specifically, I want to have an ErrorSlice (ErrorReducer) which is reset before each request, so old errors are deleted and only new errors are displayed. I could probably reset the state in each of the cases but i would like to solve this for all cases in one place

Comment: Hey, could you come up with a solution? if so, would you please post it here? thanks!